# Chinese Poem Verses About Weapons, Advice, and Israel?

Tags: translation, poetry

This is an excerpt from the end of a poem I'm working to translate:

以前之前
如风如迷的人与神
温润良言
亦如戈鋋铿锵然
让以色列都复了国
要我度过这长夜
又有何难

And this is my current translation draft.

"Long, long ago/
Like the wind, or like bewildered men and gods/
given kind, gentle words of advice/
or like the clashing and clanging of weapons/
helped restore Israel to nationhood./
How hard could it be
For me to toil away these long nights?/"

I'm not the most confident in this translation, mainly because there doesn't seem to be a strong connection between the thoughts I've tried to express in each verse. Is my interpretation of "如风如迷的人与神" correct?

Comment: 这句诗即使是我们中国人也不好翻译。
你可以在翻译时把“如”字去掉
This poem is not easy to translate even for us Chinese.
You can remove the word "如" when translating

Comment: Please don’t use the [tag:simplified-chinese] tag to request answers in Simplified Chinese - that tag is for asking questions on Simplified Chinese characters, if you need something in a particular character set you’ll have to use a third-party online converter.

Comment: Is it a poem? It seems not to me :p  It sounds like a script translated from the bible? If that is true that is def not a poem~

Answer (score 1):

The "迷" looks more like an interchangeable character of "谜" here according to the context. So I personally see the sentence better translates into "Human and gods, like winds, like enigmas".